# Connection bewteen scorecard and grid in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Scorecord's structure:

> Year   Status Target Actual
>
> 2005   2006
>
> Grid Structure
>
> Year
>
> Yes        NO
>
> Count     Count

In dashboard , I create connection between Scorecard and Grid. It works very well. For the first time, when I deploy dashboard, the grid structure shows as above, But when I click Year in scorecard, Year in Grid is below Count
Grid Structure becomes the following :

> Grid Structure
>
> Yes         NO
>              Count       Count
>
> Year         Year

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for any help..

I figure out. This is because  hierarchy  in scorecard is different from Gird.

for example, in scorecard, I used [Date].[Year].[Year], but in Grid, I used [Date].[Month].[Year]